# Azure Data Factory same pipeline for multiple for trigger parallel?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Suppose, we have parameter pipeline in Azure Data Factory which copy data from Dataset_DL_XXX (Data Lake) to Dataset_DB_XXX (Azure Database). this activity starts at 10:00 pm. At 10:05 pm we have 1 more request to copy data from Dataset_DL_YYY (Data Lake) to Dataset_DB_YYY (Azure Database).

Can we use the same pipeline to trigger multiple tasks? or do we have any other approach?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we use the same pipeline to trigger multiple tasks?

Based on my researching, it should be possible if you use control flow in the pipeline.My idea as below:

1.Firstly, please see the statements from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers):

> A pipeline run in Azure Data Factory defines an instance of a pipeline
>   execution. For example, say you have a pipeline that executes at 8:00
>   AM, 9:00 AM, and 10:00 AM. In this case, there are three separate runs
>   of the pipeline, or pipeline runs. Each pipeline run has a unique
>   pipeline run ID. A run ID is a GUID that uniquely defines that
>   particular pipeline run.

So you could trigger the same pipeline at 10 pm and 10.05 pm.Then are different pipeline runs.

2.Get the [trigger time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables) inside the pipeline:`@pipeline().TriggerTime`

3.Use [If-Condition Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity) to control that which copy activity should be executed this time.